# Proving $\sum\limits_{cyc}{\frac{xy}{x^5 + xy + y^5}} \le 1$

Tags: inequality

> Prove that $${\frac{xy}{x^5 + xy + y^5}} + {\frac{yz}{y^5 + yz + z^5}} + {\frac{zx}{z^5 + zx + z^5}}\le 1$$ for positive reals $x, y, z$ whose product is $1$.

I have tried proving the above inequality.

Since, $x^5 + y^5 \ge x^4y + xy^4$ by Muirhead's Inequality.

So, now we have to prove that $$\sum_{cyc}{\frac{1}{x^3 + y^3 + 1}} \le 1$$

I think it can be done with AM-GM inequality but am not sure.

Thanks.

Comment: The second inequality is not true for $x = y = z = 0$.

Comment: @dtldarek They are strictly positive reals. I'll edit the question. Sorry! I was missing some data. Their product is 1 too.